# TypeScript: Conditional Typing with if condition inside Array reduce()

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-conditional-types

I have a method called `groupBy` (adapted from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mikaello/06a76bca33e5d79cdd80c162d7774e9c)) that groups an array of objects based on unique key values given an array of key names. It returns an object of shape `Record<string, T[]>` by default, where `T[]` is a sub-array of the input objects. If the boolean parameter `indexes` is `true`, it instead returns `Record<string, number[]>`, where `number[]` corresponds to indexes of the input array instead of the values themselves.

I'm able to use conditional typing in the function signature to indicate that the return type changes based on the `indexes` parameter:

```
/**
 * @description Group an array of objects based on unique key values given an array of key names.
 * @param  {[Object]} array
 * @param  {[string]} keys
 * @param  {boolean} [indexes] Set true to return indexes from the original array instead of values
 * @return {Object.<string, []>} e.g. {'key1Value1-key2Value1': [obj, obj], 'key1Value2-key2Value1: [obj]}
 */
function groupBy<T>(array: T[], keys: (keyof T)[], indexes?: false): Record<string, T[]>;
function groupBy<T>(array: T[], keys: (keyof T)[], indexes?: true): Record<string, number[]>;
function groupBy<T>(
    array: T[],
    keys: (keyof T)[],
    indexes = false,
): Record<string, T[]> | Record<string, number[]> {
    return array.reduce((objectsByKeyValue, obj, index) => {
        const value = keys.map((key) => obj[key]).join('-');
        // @ts-ignore
        objectsByKeyValue[value] = (objectsByKeyValue[value] || []).concat(indexes ? index : obj);
        return objectsByKeyValue;
    }, {} as Record<string, T[]> | Record<string, number[]>);
}

const foo = groupBy([{'hey': 1}], ['hey'], true)
const bar = groupBy([{'hey': 1}], ['hey'])
```

When using the function, the two constants declared at the end have the appropriate typing, but I see the following error if I remove the `// @ts-ignore`:

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable.   
Each member of the union type 
'{ (...items: ConcatArray<number>[]): number[]; (...items: (number | ConcatArray<number>)[]): number[]; } | 
{ (...items: ConcatArray<T>[]): T[]; (...items: (T | ConcatArray<...>)[]): T[]; }' 
has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

I think I understand that this is because the conditional type isn't evaluated inside the method, so TypeScript doesn't know that the array won't have mixed types. I can resolve the error by using a larger if-else block, e.g.:

```
if (indexes) {
   return ... as Record<string, number[]>
} else {
   return ... as Record<string, T[]>
}
```

But this requires copying the entire function in both branches with just a slight difference. Is there a more clever way to use conditional types within the function so it's not necessary to duplicate the method with just a slight difference in each branch?

Comment: Function overload implementations are already more loosely typed than call signatures and you're already using at least one type assertion in there, so I'm not sure why it matters whether the compiler can follow the logic.  Why not just loosen it a little more so that the implementation returns `Record<string, (T | number)[]` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbKr4W)?  Does that work for you or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementations of [overloaded functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) are intentionally checked more loosely than the set of call signatures.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235) for more information.  That means it isn't necessarily worth trying to convince the compiler that what you're doing is correct, since if you fail to do it properly, it will still probably not notice your mistake.  With that in mind, the general approach to overload implementations is to double and triple check that your logic is correct (since the compiler can't) and then loosen the types up enough so that this correct implementation doesn't have compiler errors.

For your example code I'd probably just return `Record<string, (T | number)[]>` from the implementation, like this:

```
function groupBy<T>(array: T[], keys: (keyof T)[], indexes: false): Record<string, T[]>;
function groupBy<T>(array: T[], keys: (keyof T)[], indexes?: true): Record<string, number[]>;
function groupBy<T>(
    array: T[],
    keys: (keyof T)[],
    indexes = false,
) {
    return array.reduce<Record<string, (T | number)[]>>((objectsByKeyValue, obj, index) => {
        const value = keys.map((key) => obj[key]).join('-');
        objectsByKeyValue[value] = (objectsByKeyValue[value] || []).concat(indexes ? index : obj);
        return objectsByKeyValue;
    }, {});
}
```

Here I've manually specified the generic type parameter to `reduce()` as `Record<string, (T | number)[]>` which is slightly more type safe than writing `{} as Record<string, (T | number)[]>` (but that would also be fine), which lets the compiler know that the return value is `Record<string, (T | number)[]>`, which is accepted according to the loose overload rules.

So now there are no compiler errors.  Again, this doesn't mean the code is safe; you could change `.concat(indexes ? index : obj)` to `.concat(!indexes ? index : obj)` and still have no compiler errors. So do be careful with overloads and take care that your algorithm works how you think it does.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgBAJgUwM4GMBOBLADgF2wHsA7aAcUyIFddoBDM+zTegT2iIDNOAjAK2Tp8qaL3qpkiTmWolsAR2rJoAa2QcAbvQA2y0QHNsm5EyYt2nHuo4l6AWzQA6KLAS5mD6NADeAbQB5ASF8AF0AXwYLNlc4eA9We29-VHwcEgMItQ1UWPdPJN9eIiIdZEZIv2wSFAAPNFDoAGVkfGg05XaiaExW6kwyarq0aC4qJPwACxUiHCM7HSjWDmrU8uluaG09NDz4Xvx+sh8gwWEnAB5U9IMAGmg-UIA+SOQnAydfAHIbAEYANV0yl+AFobAAmQE7X5fABcDyIAnuiP4oXuPw0AKByHBYI0kOxv3hfhREViwCgXDkwmIZAMVFoACE2BcACpPAAUzGW8NZj3uNlQ8I5Nk2rIAlPzoENkPUhaNdJJxfCAEpCWaIK5pap3aB854Abkp1MIpGg9JouGZbM53PYvKlguFop4EqlMrlAH54R1kMroGr0BqtTd7iRqPZeMhMI8nkbIFSSDSzRamSz2RzXN4lva9fys94ndARRoxZK0QXpTVZSMALwKnSSW5QcW+SsHI45thOXqIajoZAXQPB646+4c1nQAA+0HDkej5aenI5KJCqGZAGkNFDlMikVW6q3a082zBs+egyRUltsdB64KnPZ6LgOSW2EeTyi-DZQuKnPwiGqDkvhBL5xXjc9z1XYR1zYLc2B3ZA-G2ZRGnrFdghgzdt2xZDsUaKcZ0eP9L3Qeh8A5D0Rk9A9ZWgeEUXAytzw7AY+DOERsIQ7EIOzcJ7h8cImMgcIoCgS9ry4Eo73NBkrTYDk-B8aAvmmNg4WgX5oHCNEHlUjQvl031xXE0hr3ETAZNTeTFOU-T1PhLSdPuPx7MM8UgA)